# Setting row background colour in XAML DataGrid based on edit state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

The following XAML works fine for changing the background colour when the row is being edited:

```
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
          <Setter Property="Background"  Value="AntiqueWhite" />
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But I would also like the following behaviours:

- Change back to default colour after saved
- If edit is undone, change back to default colour

Any suggestions on how to do this?

**UPDATE:**

A little more clarity - it behaves as I would expect the above code to - just looking for something different.  It changes the back colour but only when I am editing the row. When I navigate off that row (before saving changes) the background colour reverts back to default.  I would like the edit backcolour to stay on each edited row until the changes are saved.  If I change the data back to the unchanged stat before I save, I would like the background colour to reset back to default.

Here is more of the code:

```
    <DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTransactionList}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Name="TransactionTable" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RowEditEnding="TransactionTable_RowEditEnding">
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="AntiqueWhite" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="Gray" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Label}" />
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Stat" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Stat}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource stats}}"  Width="125" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Change" Binding="{Binding Change}" Width="75" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The TransactionTable_RowEditEnding event handler just enables the Update Button.

This is the relavent ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<StatTransactionValue> currentTransactionList;
    public ObservableCollection<StatTransactionValue> CurrentTransactionList {
        get { return currentTransactionList; }
        set {
            if (value != currentTransactionList) {
                currentTransactionList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTransactionList");
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetCurrentTransactionList(long ItemId) {
        CurrentTransactionList = Gateway.GetTransactions(ItemId);
    }

    public void UpdateTransactions() {
        Gateway.UpdateTransactions(CurrentTransactionList);
    }
```

The Gateway is a simple call to Sqlite using ServiceStack OrmLite Sqlite.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a new property on the view model, something like `IsDirty`, then you can trigger on that using a `DataTrigger`, you'll of course have to change the property yourself using the right `DataGrid` events or internal change notifications.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing this - keeping a collection of edited ids.  The logic to colour the edited/updated row is too complex for triggers so needed to be done in code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would take a look at setting the [UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) and then firing the [UpdateSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) method when you want to commit the changes to the viewmodel. This way you can specify when the editing of the properties actually happens.

I would play around with this see how the IsEditing corresponds to it. I have never really used this UpdateSourceTrigger value before so I have no idea. It would at the very least control the way the properties are updated well.

Otherwise if this is no good then what H.B. said is spot on, that's the way you should do it.